# Что означают типы данных signed и unsigned

Tags: c++

читаю книгу и тут есть signed char и unsigned char вроде что-то пишут про различный объем памяти, но я все равно не понимаю что это и как этим пользоваться.

Comment: А как переводится signed?

Comment: @MBo подписанный =)

Comment: Подойдет? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337217/difference-between-signed-unsigned-char

Answer (score 2):

Если коротко, то это значит знаковый или беззнаковый тип. Само понятие берется из реализации хранения значения в памяти. на вашем примере signed char/unsigned char - занимают в памяти 1 байт, т.е. 8 бит и соответственно минимальное значение 0, и максимальное значение - 2^8-1=255

```
|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|
```

Но если вам нужны отрицательные числа, то в этом байте придется выделить один бит, указывающий знак числа (+/-)

```
|0|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|
 ^
 Знак
```

И соответственно на само значени у вас остается 7бит, т.е. 2^7-1 = 127, и диапазон значений [-128:127]

Дополнительно обратите внимание на особенности переполнения знаковых типов - они могут менять знак (при перпеполении единица заедет в знаковый разряд

```
signed char c=127; // 127- 01111111
c++; //  10000000 = , или -128
```

Comment: Знаковое переполнение - UB.

Comment: если знаешь что делаешь, то это может стать не багом в фичей. это так же как с не виртуальным множественным наследованием - для одних засада, для других возможность.

Comment: @SergeyTatarintsev, рекламировать UB как возможность - плохая идея. 1. Тут этого не любят. 2. Как часто вы читали документацию по компилятору и проверяли сгенерированный машинный код чтобы убедится что действительно получится арифметика по модулю. Ни разу? Я так и знал.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy делают собственно что и ожидалось  c++ это addl, который безусловно перекроет знаковый бит. при этом компилятор принципиально знать не может для какого значения будет вызван этот ++. Эти приколы только в рантайм

Comment: Префиксный инкремент `++x` по стандарту [эквивалентен](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.pre.incr#1) выражению `x+=1`. Для постфиксного инкремента `x++` модификация операнда происходит также, как вычисляется выражение `x+=1`. (На самом деле процесс модификации аргумента для постфиксного инкремента в стандарте [написан](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.post.incr#1) расплывчато: `The value of the operand object is modified by adding 1 to it`, но cppreference [настаивает](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec), что это следует понимать так: ...

Comment: ...`As a side-effect, the expression x++ modifies the value of its operand as if by evaluating x += 1`. Таким образом в коде `signed char c=127; c++;` знакового целочисленного переполнения нет, т.к. прибавление целочисленного литерала `1` типа `int` приводит к тому, что промежуточные вычисления выполняются над типом `int`, а он гарантированно может вместить целое `128`. Затем полученный результат приводится к типу `signed char`. Результат такого приведения, начиная с C++20, [однозначно определён](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.integral#3). Ранее был implementation-defined.

Comment: Тем не менее соглашусь с предыдущими комментаторами в том, что [не следует полагаться на UB и гарантированно ожидать модулярную арифметику от знакового целочисленного переполнения](https://godbolt.org/z/sY36Tavhv).

Comment: То-есть как я понял unsigned char отличается от signed тем что в signed приходится забирать один бит для определения знака числа, а в unsigned такого нет и по этому в unsigned помещается в 2 раза больше чисел, при условии того что в переменной не будет отрицательных чисел.